# Why "0" is rendered on short-circuit evaluation of `array.length && ...`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, render

Currently, I see behavior like this:

```
render() {
   const list = [];
   return (
      <div>
         { list.length && <div>List rendered</div> }
      </div>
   )
}
```

My expected is nothing rendered with that condition, but string "0" rendered (string "0" is `list.length`). I don't know why. Anybody can help me explain this case to React?

Comment: You need to make it as a ternary operator. Something like `{ list.length ? <div>List rendered</div> : ""}` should work for you.

Comment: array.length is a javascript thing not a react thing. add a condition {list.length>0 && } . it will work fine

Comment: Yes, I know this case resolved by many solutions. But I need why with this case.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's basically the way, [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) works:

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested
> for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> (some falsy expression) && expr is short-circuit **evaluated to the
> falsy expression**

Thus, for an empty array, 0 is returned by the line `{ list.length && <div>List rendered</div> }`.

While `list.length` is evaluated as falsy here, [it is not ignored on render](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html?#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored) as opposed to `false`, `null`, `undefined` or `true`.

So, if you want your short-circuit expression to return one of the ignored values, you may return a boolean from your leftmost expression:

```
{ list.length>0 && <div>List rendered</div> }
```

Or [cast](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!) the value returned by the expression to a boolean, like that:

```
{ !!list.length && <div>List rendered</div> }
```

Following is a quick demo as a proof of concept:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM

const Component = () => {
  const list = []
  return (
      <div>
         <div>Rendered on <code>{`list.length && <div>List rendered</div>`}</code>:{ list.length && <div>List rendered</div> }</div>
         <div>Rendered on <code>{`list.length>0 && <div>List rendered</div>`}</code>:{ list.length>0 && <div>List rendered</div> }</div>
         <div>Rendered on <code>{`!!list.length && <div>List rendered</div>`}</code>:{ !!list.length && <div>List rendered</div> }</div>
      </div>
   )
}

render (<Component />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
code {background-color: grey; color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This isn't related to React really, but rather to JavaScript directly:

```
const output = list.length && "foobar";
```

If `list.length` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), then `output` will take its value (so `0` in this case), and not `false` as one might think.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late to answer it but i would like to express my understandings.

As other answer by @sp00m explains clearly that it is not related to ***React*** but it is a feature of javascript.

What it does?

When the left side is falsy then it will take the value of it as in your case it will be `0` because of the `[].length`.  This causes to print `"0"` in the DOM.

Solution:

You can make it for a truthy expectation like `[].length > 0` or `[].length !== 0` or `!![].length` or make a ternary operator to show the component dom.
The last one converts the falsy/truthy values to a boolean value.