# How can conditionally render items in functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code

```
export default function Autocomplete() {


  return (
    <div className="wrapper" >
      <div  className={ isLoading ? 'is-loading control' : 'control' } >
        <input type="text" className="input" onChange={onInputClick}/>
      </div>
      {
        <div className="list is-hoverable">
        {response.map(item => {
          return <a className="list-item">{item}</a>
        })}
      </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

how can I conditionally check if the response - so response. length is equal to zero then I should not render this part

```
 <div className="list is-hoverable">
        {response.map(item => {
          return <a className="list-item">{item}</a>
        })}
```

Comment: You can use the logical and operator `&&`  `{response.length && <div className=".........etc`

Comment: can't you just wrap in `if (response.length > 0) { ..... }` ?

Comment: @GrafiCode  Not in mid JSX...

Comment: There is absolutely no need to ask this on SO when it is completely explained in the docs... https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breactjs%5D+conditional+jsx

Comment: @PRSHL  Actually pretty much everything on SO is mentioned in some Doc's somewhere.   And having SO act as a Doc helper is exactly what SO is for.  And even Dup's a good thing, as the way questions are asked, may differ, so having Dup's helps with search terms.

Comment: @Keith when the answer is explicitly covered in the docs with a near identical code snippet included it is totally legitimate to direct the OP to the docs, plus the fact that this question is a duplicate many times over.

Comment: @Keith may be useful when people are asking questions about problems which are explained somewhere in some huge docs. But not if you are asking questions about core concepts from a framework which are even explained in the 'MAIN CONCEPTS' section of the docs.

Comment: @pilchard  It's always a good idea to point users to relevant Docs, nobody said otherwise.  And Dup's are not a bad thing, SO has the ability to link Dups, so if you find the Dup, you can link them.  Having the question asked again, helps SO, especially with search engines, questions can be asked in slightly different ways, so having SO Dups helps with this.   I remember a meta debate on the whole issue of Dups, in a nutshell as long a Dup's are not a simple Copy / Paste, they have value..

Comment: @Keith your commented solution will render a 0 if response is an empty array.

Comment: @pilchard  Good point,  ` > 0 && `  or `Boolean(items.length)` ,  `!!items.length` , or even the ternary if the OP wants to be specific should fix that bit.  I'm so used to conditions already been boolean.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function Autocomplete() {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className={isLoading ? "is-loading control" : "control"}>
                <input type="text" className="input" onChange={onInputClick} />
            </div>
            {response.length > 0 && (
                <div className="list is-hoverable">
                    {response.map(item => {
                        return <a className="list-item">{item}</a>;
                    })}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

You can do `response.length > 0 && (<div>......</div>)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use conditional rendering using the `condition ? true : false` or `&&` operator

```
  return (
    <div className="wrapper" >
      <div  className={ isLoading ? 'is-loading control' : 'control' } >
        <input type="text" className="input" onChange={onInputClick}/>
      </div>
      {
        <div className="list is-hoverable">
        {response.length && response.map(item => {
          return <a className="list-item">{item}</a>
        })}
      </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @pilchard yeah my bad

Comment: How can i hide the 0 in this case ?

Comment: the 0 means false in javascript conditions so it works perfectly

Comment: You need to force `response.length` to a boolean or React will render the 0, so `{!!response.length && response.map(item => {...`. (React won't render `false` or `null` but will render 0) (also 0 doesn't *mean false*, it is simply a falsy value when evaluated as a boolean)

Comment: see: [Why "0" is rendered on short-circuit evaluation of `array.length && ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60652656/why-0-is-rendered-on-short-circuit-evaluation-of-array-length)